# Getting Undefined variable: type in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am getting this message
[image]

While trying to load a page. And its indicating to this line of code

```
return view('admin/vehicle-categories/index',compact('categories','level','parent_categories','type','parent_id'));

}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: we can see your variables?

Comment: You don't have a variable `$type` that `compact` function can use when constructing the array.

Answer (score 1):

This was a breaking change introduced in PHP 7.2.  Previously you could compact a named variable that was not yet defined.  After 7.2 you must define the variable previous to adding to the `compact` method.

Broke a lot of code for us as well.

The fix is to simply define the variable before the compact statement, even if null.  Be careful if going through a branch/if-check that you define it for certain:

```
$type == null // or value
```